# How cast array[4] to array[2][2]?

Tags: c, arrays, casting

I have a array `short frame[4]` and I want it as a function parameter as `short frame[2][2]`

How can I cast it? I tried different things (like `*(short [2][2])&frame[0]*)`, but I still get error messages.

Also not working is if I declare the function with `void function(short frame[2][2])`
and call the function with `function(&frame[0])` while `frame` is a `short frame[4];`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Convert from 2 indices to a single index like this: `z = y * 2 + x;` and back like this `x = z % 2; y = z / 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here, albeit with a warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void function(short frame[2][2])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
      printf("%d ", frame[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
  short frame[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
  function(&frame[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

What error message do you get?

Comment: i tried this also, but.... oh, excuse me! you are right! it was just a warning, not an error! it works, thanks! :)

Comment: Warnings shall mainly be fixed.

Comment: @Kirilenko The Right Fix would require that the two `frame` be of the same type… But this would not answer user1859796’s question. Muffling the warning through a cast to `short (*)[2]` smells: I prefer to be warned.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a good pratice, anyway:

```
f((short (*)[2])a);
```

Comment: +1. The reason this works is that *as a function parameter* `short frame[2][2]` means the same as `short (*frame)[2]`. I think the argument as to whether this violates strict aliasing or not is a bit tricky, though. I can't remember the outcome, so it certainly wouldn't be a good practice for *me* to assume that it doesn't. Others' confidence in its validity may be higher, but either way it's what the questioner asked for ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast between different dimensional arrays.

It wouldn't know which way round you wanted it.

You'll have to write a function.

In pseudocode:

```
function castArray(short[4] input){
   short[2][2] output = new short[2][2];
   output[0][0] = input[0];
   output[0][1] = input[1];
   output[1][0] = input[2];
   output[1][1] = input[3];
   return output;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to copy. In memory the bytes of array[4] are one after the other like  

0x34 -> array[0]  
0x35 -> array[1]  
...

for a better usability i want the access to this memory as  

0x34 -> array[0][0]  
0x35 -> array[0][1]  
0x36 -> array[1][0]  
...

Answer (score 0):

You achieve it an easy way like this :

Converting 1-D array into 2-D array

```
short frame[MAX];
short dup_frame[ROW][COL];
int i,j,k;
for(i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++)
{
  j= i / ROW ;  // you can do it by i / COL also 
  k= i % ROW ; // you can do it by i % COL also 
  dup_frame[j][k] = frame[i];
}
```